# DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body when trying to create multiple commands

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm learning to create a discord bot and i faced an error that i can't figure out how to solve... I was trying to create multiple commands with objects in array. When i was doing just one object without using the array it was warking but as soon as i created the array and inserted 2 commands it throw me the following error:

```
I:\botDiscord\secondo-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
name: Command name is invalid
    at RequestHandler.execute (I:\botDiscord\secondo-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (I:\botDiscord\secondo-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async GuildApplicationCommandManager.set (I:\botDiscord\secondo-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\ApplicationCommandManager.js:146:18)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (I:\botDiscord\secondo-bot\index.js:39:4) {
  method: 'put',
  path: '/applications/970439955660812309/guilds/968170513774039201/commands',
  code: 50035,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: {
    json: [
      {
        name: 'Ping',
        description: 'risponde pong',
        type: undefined,
        options: undefined,
        default_permission: undefined
      },
      {
        name: 'pong',
        description: 'risponde ping',
        type: undefined,
        options: undefined,
        default_permission: undefined
      }
    ],
    files: []
  }
}

Node.js v18.0.0
```

And here is the code that i used for receive this error... please help me... is more than 6 hour that I'm trying to understand where is my mistake.

Obviously where I put 'My_Discord_Id' and 'My_Bot_id' i used to insert the relevants ids

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({
  intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES],
});

client.once("ready", () => {
  console.log("Bot Online");
});

client.on("interactionCreate", async(interaction) => {
  if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

  if (interaction.commandName === "ping") {
    await interaction.reply({
      content: "pong",
      ephimeral: true
    });
  } else if (interaction.commandName === "pong") {
    await interaction.editReply({
      content: "ping",
      ephemeral: true,
    });
  }
});

client.on("messageCreate", async(message) => {
  if (!client.application ? .owner) await client.application ? .fetch();

  if (message.author.id === client.application ? .owner.id) {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() == "!reg1") {
      const data = [{
          name: "Ping",
          description: "risponde pong",
        },
        {
          name: "pong",
          description: "risponde ping",
        },
      ];
      await client.guilds.cache
        .get("My_Discord_Id") ?
        .commands.set(data);
    }
  }
});

client.login("My_Bot_Id");
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue does not really have anything to do with your code logic. The issue is essentially a typo. Slash command names simply do not support capital letters. In your code, you are creating a slash command named "Ping", as shown below:

```js
const data = [{
        name: "Ping",
        description: "risponde pong",
    },
    {
        name: "pong",
        description: "risponde ping",
    },
];
```

Just rename that to its lowercase form, "ping", and the error you are getting will be fixed. Like so:

```js
const data = [{
        name: "ping",
        description: "risponde pong",
    },
    {
        name: "pong",
        description: "risponde ping",
    },
];
```